# is there a basis $\{e_1,\cdots, e_n\}$ so that $\phi_g e_i \in \{e_1,\cdots, e_n\}$ for all g in G?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, permutations, representation-theory

> Prove or disprove whether every representation $(V,\phi)$ of a finite group G has a basis $\{e_1,\cdots, e_n\}$ so that $\phi_g e_i\in \{e_1,\cdots, e_n\}$ for all i, $g\in G$.

I know about representations like the regular representation and the permutation representation. This question seems to ask about a "general" permutation representation.

If V's dimension is the same as G's cardinality, the answer seems to be yes. Choose any basis $\{e_1,\cdots, e_n\}$ of $V$ and associate $g_i $ with $e_i$ where $g_i$ is the ith element of G under a fixed ordering. Then define a representation $\phi : G \to GL(V)$ by letting $\phi(g_j)e_i = v(g_j g_i),$ where $v(g_j g_i)$ is the corresponding basis element of $g_j g_i\in G$.

Answer (score 3):

If there were such a basis, $e_1+\cdots+e_n\in V$ will be fixed by $G$, i.e., $V$ would contain the trivial representation. So for example the sign representation of $C_2$ is a counter-example.

Comment: Thanks. Just to confirm, the sign representation $\phi$ of $C_2 = \{1,s\}$ sends 1 to 1 and s to -1. Then there is no basis $\{b\}$ of $\mathbb{C}^*$ so that $\phi(g)b \in \{b\}$ for all $b\in B,$ right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. [In fact, a representation admits such a basis if and only if it is a permutation representation (associated to the action of the group on the basis)]

Answer (score 0):

For any such representation, the trace of $\phi_g$ is an integer in $[0, n]$, which rules out many representations, including the sign representation of $C_2$.